# Simulator for HDPCD

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig, hortonworks-data-platform, hortonworks-sandbox

I am studying HDPCD and trying to prepare myself for HDPCD exam. I have downloaded Sandbox and practicing there, but also would like to make myself familiar with the exam environment through a simulator.

I have found this 
https://2xbbhjxc6wk3v21p62t8n4d4-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/HDPCD-PracticeExamGuide1.pdf

but that AMI "“Hortonworks HDPCDeveloper_x.x PracticeExam_vx", mentioned in Step 3.3. P5, is not available anymore in AWS, so the question is, How can I practice the exam in a simulated environment in AWS.

Available AMIs
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit misleading, but I had to change the region
[image]